# How to let yasnippet support PyQt in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pyqt

I used emacs as Python IDE. I have install yasnippet, but how can I get it to support PyQt?
This is my .emacs:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(if (load "auto-complete-scite-api" t)
    (setq-default ac-sources (cons 'ac-source-scite-api ac-sources)))
(ac-config-default)

(require 'auto-complete-yasnippet)
(require 'pymacs)
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)

(require 'python)
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas/initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet/snippets")
(yas/global-mode 1)
(require 'python-mode)

(require 'django-html-mode)
(require 'django-mode)
(yas/load-directory "/home/jactry/.emacs.d/snippets")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml$" . django-html-mode))

(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

I use Ubuntu and have install auto-complete and yasnippt,I want to let my emacs have a code autp complete of PyQt.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you installed `yasnippets` however, i used el-get and i don't think it should matter with what I'm about to write.

1. Create a directory called `~/.emacs.d/snippets/pyqt`
2. open up a pyqt file in emacs.
3. Under the YaSnippet top menu, choose `New Snippet` (or `C+c & C+n`)
4. Save the file with just the snippet letters you want to hit. My sample file i saved as just `l`
5. When done saving, reload your snippets using `Reload Everything` well that's what i do, the other one was too finicky for me.

You will get a file that kind of looks like this, only I filled it out:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: label (l)
# key: l
# --
<label>
  $0
</label>
```

That should be it.  you may have to adjust PyQt in the directory name, but it should be all lowercase. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks at first!Maybe I express it in a wrong way.I just want to let my emacs have a PyQt and Python code auto compelet.I used Ubuntu and I have installed auto-complete and yasnippets by Ubuntu software source.

Comment: From what it sounds like you are saying, you have it installed but it's not working for both modes: python files and pyQT files. correct?  if so, what's your dotemacs file look like?  yasnippet can have some interesting configuration. I recommend a package manager like el-get though. Some of that magic gets hidden for you.

Comment: I have showed my .emacs. And auto complete of python is working.But isn't perfect as I want.I want it when I type "`os.pa`" and it will auto complete "`os.path`" and so on.

Comment: you mean `os.pa<tabkey>` right?  or do you want it to appear with a list of possible completions without hitting tab?

Comment: Yes!And I want it include class and module of PyQt.So sorry to my poor english.

Comment: Your english is fine. I may have taken you as far as i can though, sorry. does the emacs wiki have anything about pyqt at all?

Comment: I can't find anything in that.And I tired to Google with keywork "emacs autp complete pyqt",also can't find anything worth.Thanks a lot.